# CREATE TABLE Failed. 3707: Syntax error, expected something like a string or a Unicode character literal between the 'FORMAT' keyword and '('

Tags: sql, teradata

CREATE TABLE Failed. 3707:  Syntax error, expected something like a string or a Unicode character literal between the 'FORMAT' keyword and '('.
i'm getting this answer

```
CREATE TABLE Dp_Stg2.WOR ( 
WorkOrderID int,
ProductID INT,
OperationSequence INT ,
LocationID INT ,
ScheduledStartDate DATE FORMAT('yyyy-mm-dd'),
ScheduledEndDate DATE FORMAT('yyyy-mm-dd'),
ActualStartDate DATE FORMAT('yyyy-mm-dd'),
ActualEndDate DATE FORMAT( 'DD-MM-YY'),
ActualResourceHrs FLOAT ,
PlannedCost FLOAT ,
ActualCost FLOAT ,
ModifiedDate DATE FORMAT ('yyyy-mm-dd') ) PRIMARY INDEX ( WorkOrderID ) FROM Dp_Stg1.WOR; –
```

Comment: Please add your syntax to clarify your problem

Comment: CREATE TABLE Dp_Stg2.WOR
(
       WorkOrderID int,ProductID INT,OperationSequence INT ,LocationID INT ,ScheduledStartDate DATE FORMAT('yyyy-mm-dd'),ScheduledEndDate DATE FORMAT('yyyy-mm-dd'),ActualStartDate DATE FORMAT('yyyy-mm-dd'),ActualEndDate DATE FORMAT( 'DD-MM-YY'),ActualResourceHrs FLOAT ,PlannedCost FLOAT ,ActualCost FLOAT ,ModifiedDate DATE FORMAT ('yyyy-mm-dd') )
PRIMARY INDEX  ( WorkOrderID ) 
FROM Dp_Stg1.WOR;

Comment: You can always [edit] your question to add more detail; comments aren't suitable for this.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No parentheses: `FORMAT'yyyy-mm-dd'` and what's `FROM Dp_Stg1.WOR`?

Comment: let me try mate

Comment: thats file which i fastloaded from teradata database

Comment: sAME ERROR AGAIN AND AGAIN

Comment: Again, `FROM Dp_Stg1.WOR` - this is simply not valid DDL.  What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: I think he is trying to create an externally-linked table, like in Oracle, which is unlikely to be possible in TD.